# Storing checkbox values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a set of 3 checkboxes that ask the user for input. They are constructed like this:

```
<span class="playback-format-checkbox-holder">
    <span><b>Playback Format</span><br />
        <label for="dvd">
          <input type="checkbox" name="playback_format[]" value="dvd"  id="dvd" />
        DVD
        </label>
        <label for="bluray">
          <input type="checkbox" name="playback_format[]" value="bluray"  id="bluray" />
        Bluray
        </label>
        <label for="3d">
          <input type="checkbox" name="playback_format[]" value="3d" id="3d"  />
        3D
        </label>
</span>
```

and I am posting the results like so

```
<?php
   $new = array();

   $playback_formats = $_POST['playback_format'];

   if ( isset($playback_formats) ) {
     $new['playback_format'] = $playback_formats;           
   }
?>
```

If I select two values, only one is returned. For example, if i select bluray and 3d, the array only stores bluray. If I check dvd and 3d only dvd is stored. So only the first selection is being stored in the playback_format array.

What have I done wrong?

If I check one checkbox in each row it returns the correct values. the playback_format[] array is not storing as an array. Why?

If I check two boxes in the first row, and leave the second row blank the first row gets the first selection and the second row gets the second.

I have no idea what is going on. This seems like it shouldn't be this difficult...

---

This is when I check DVD and Bluray on the first set of checkboxes, and leave the second set of checkboxes blank.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [select] =>
Testing Title #1

[url] =>
Description #1

[playback_format] => Array ( [0] => bluray ) ) [1] => Array ( [select] =>
Testing Title #2

[url] =>
Description #2

[playback_format] => Array ( [0] => dvd ) ) ) )
testing a new list
```

As you can see, its not storing in the correct array. The second checkbox value has been stored in the second array for whatever reason, and not in the first row playback_format array.

This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Have you tried printing $new? check what values having in $new. I've tested above code as it is and working good.

Comment: I have, I am printing out the variable and it's storing the variables in random locations. The values are not stored in an array per line.

Comment: could you show your output? because its working fine at my side.

Comment: Sure, check above. I added it to the bottom.

Comment: Still nothing here, huh. Such a simple issue with no working solution. Who would have thought such a simple task would become so damn difficult.

Answer (score 0):

you just try to foreach,  i think that will better idea

```
foreach ($playback_format as $3d){}
```

Comment: am I adding that to where I post my results? `if ( isset($playback_formats[$i]) ) {
    foreach ($playback_formats[$i] as $playback) {
     $new[$i]['playback_format'] = $playback;
    }    
   }`